# Confusion in meaning of word "classic"?

Tags: meaning, terminology, phrase-meaning, dictionaries

[image]I have searched the meaning of "classic" in Cambridge dictionary, but I am not satisfied about its meaning as adjective

What is difference between terms **classic** and **old**? As we often use terms like for example classic physics, classic music, etc..

Comment: 1. Use a **dictionary** - not a search engine!  2. Tell us what you found and why you are still confused: *e.g.* someone might be an 'old person' - but would you ever describe them as a 'classic person'?!  Voted to close for lack of research.

Comment: i often read texts of physics where they discuss about classic physics .In which they discuss about laws of old scientists like newton,Einstein   and when i study south asian culture they say that classical music and then they refer to names of old musicians of area just like nusrat fateh ali

Comment: Sorry, just realised you are new here!  Please refer to [How do I ask a good question](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn a little more about what is expected on this site.

Comment: Einstein may be old to some people, but I would hesitate to put him in the category of a classical physicist along with Newton.

Comment: https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/classic

Comment: Thank you for providing a dictionary definition of 'classic'.  What do you not understand about the difference between (1) "having a high quality or standard ..." and (2) "Old"?

Comment: @TrevorD I think he has noticed that many old things are classics, and many classics are old, so he is wondering if the words are related, and if not, why they seem to be.

Comment: @engr The words "Classic" and "Classical" are related but they do not mean exactly the same thing. In each of physics, art, architecture and history, "Classical" has a specific meaning.

Comment: @Ben I had guessed that - but refer to my *first* comment at the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Classic" generally means "Of the highest class", i.e. something very good and worth noting and preserving.

Many old things are classics, and many classics are old. However this is not because the meanings are related, but due to a cause-and-effect relationship between the two properties.

Many of the very old things we have are classics: This is because things of the highest class are things worth preserving, and have often been preserved, sometimes for thousands of years. Whereas old things which are not of the highest class are not preserved, because they are not worth preserving.